# How to move block to lib

Tags: ruby

Let we have some module or gem (or pool of them) which provide API. Teese API's we can not modify. The API's have interface that requre blok. Let the API called `MyClass` and it have method `foo` that reuire block. We need to write enough code to block content. We need to write nubmer of such blocks. So we have number of modules with such API's that require block and number of block implementations to API's. Let's call our block code as `some code`. The integral completed code example for such case looks like this:

```
MyClass.foo do
  some code
end
```

In this short example we can see class `MyClass` with method `foo` and block with our `some code` in it.

Let we want easily replace class and method and code in block or whole block. We need to do refactoring **move block to lib** (or with move to gem) for each variant of our block implementation.

I write question after answer, and question can not have answer in it, so I need to use `...` instead of asked ruby sintax. The refactored code with no block or with no our implementation called `some come` (it moved to lib) looks like this:

```
MyClass.foo ...
```

Now the new library created during refactoring, where asked ruby code unknown and represented as `...`. looks like this:

`lib/Lib.rb`:

```
...
  some code
...
```

Here in library we can see our implementation `some code` or block with our `some code` and need to see some another ruby specific sintax that necessary to solve task.

What I need to write instead of `...` in examples above. I'd like to know all possible dodge, stroke, methods and receptions to do such refactoring, and all possible solutions of this task for easily combining given API's and ready implementations.

Comment: The devote with no reason is more unuseful than unuseful questions. What's wrong with question or typography?

Comment: Most likely your question is being downvoted because it doesn't make sense. The close votes are for that reason. I'd recommend reading "[ask]" including the linked pages.

Comment: You do not disclose the reason. For example overflowing stack make not sense too (at first sight). Stack oveflow is for help to redirect to good way from wrong way. Down vote to close question and does not show reason mean: Hey, you can not swim - drown!

Comment: Stack Overflow is to document and help provide answers to programming questions, primarily about code being written. Doing that requires the questions be well asked, to make sense to those trying to help, and for those in the future who seek an answer to the same question. Your question isn't well defined, i.e. is hard to understand, and people are down voting it along with voting to close it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)” is important too.

Comment: Tha was seemed to me that you mean that to do such refactoring does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer highly depends on how `some code` is stored in `Lib.rb`. I assume that it is not free standing code like in a script, but rather contained in a `Proc`, function or (class/module) method. What you can do then is just change the `some code` in your original block to a call to the respective object like this:

#### For `Proc`s of any kind

In `Lib.rb`

```
some_code = proc { some code }  # or
some_code = Proc.new { some code }  # or
some_code = lambda { some code }  # or
some_code = -> { some code }
```

The call:

```
MyClass.foo do
  some_code.call  # or
  some_code[]  # or
  some_code.()
end
```

#### For instance methods

In `Lib.rb`:

```
def SomeClass
  def some_code
    some code
  end
end
```

The call:

```
# Somewhere else
some_instance = SomeClass.new

MyClass.foo do
  some_instance.some_code
end
```

#### For class (or module) methods

In `Lib.rb`:

```
class SomeClass
  def self.some_code
    some code
  end
end
```

The call:

```
MyClass.foo do
  SomeClass::some_code
end
```

### The alternative: passing blocks explicitly

An interesting alternative is to pass things as an explicit parameter that Ruby then interprets as blocks. Every function `f` accepting a block can be called like this:

```
f(other, parameters, &something)
```

The `&` in front of the `something` instructs Ruby to call `to_proc` (if it is not already a `Proc`) on `something` and pass the result as the block that `f` expects.

How `something` has to look again depends on `Lib.rb`:

#### For `Proc`s

```
MyClass.foo(&some_code)
```

#### For instance methods

```
MyClass.foo(&some_instance.method(:some_code))
```

using [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-method).

#### For class/module methods

This one is tricky since these are actually basically instance methods of the metaclass, which you can get like this:

```
SomeMetaClass = class << SomeClass; self; end
```

Then you can proceed as above:

```
MyClass.foo(SomeMetaClass.method(:some_code))
```

Comment: Excellent overview. This is exactly what I need. The answer and the vote. Thanks.

Comment: If you would like to replace self defined 'method' to some another name ('foo') I will replace too.

Comment: Did it and also renamed `Class` to `MyClass` (since `Class` already exists, but `Class#foo` does not ;)). I also edited your question, you only need to accept it.